# Move marker without reloading map in android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-markers

My app has multiple locations which saved in a list(currently navigation drawer list). When user click each list row it will show the appropriate location on Google Map which is in  a fragment.
So when I click on each list row it loads the map fragment each time which takes time and consume resource.

**Is their any way to avoid this.( i.e when I click on each list row ,it just loads the marker followed by the list location contents without reloading the map again and again).**

In my Activity i called this method on each list click.

```
private void displayView(int position) {
    ChildrenLocationDetails collection = result.get(position);      
    Fragment frag = newInstance(collection.getLatitude(), collection.getLongitude());
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, frag).commit();  
}
```

And My `newInstance()` Method which sends data to Fragment:

```
public static MapFragment newInstance(double latitude, double longitude) {
    MapFragment f = new MapFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putDouble(KEY_LON, longitude);
    args.putDouble(KEY_LAT, latitude);
    f.setArguments(args);
    return f;
}
```

in my Mapfragment I collect all information and load the map with location marker.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes. As Rod_Algonquin said you just need to hide and show the FragmentTransaction and call the  user defined method of your fragment to load the marker.

If i modify it a little and help you with a friendly way then it should be more helpful.

here you can also take the help of `SharedPreferences`. Just save the changed location in else part and get them in your fragment's method.

Just do same as Rod said in your Activity with a little change.like:

```
    private void displayView(int position) {
    ChildrenLocationDetails collection = result.get(position);      
    if(frag == null){
        frag = newInstance(collection.getLatitude(), collection.getLongitude());
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, frag).commit();  
    }
    else{
        SharedPreferences mPreferences = getSharedPreferences("LOCATION", 0);
        Editor mEditor = mPreferences.edit();
        mEditor.putString(KEY_LAT, String.valueOf(collection.getLatitude()));
        mEditor.putString(KEY_LON, String.valueOf(collection.getLongitude()));
        mEditor.commit();
        MapFragment.ChangeMarkerPosition(this);
    }       
}
```

And in your Fragment's `ChangeMarkerPosition()` just do like:

```
    public static void ChangeMarkerPosition(Context context){
    SharedPreferences mPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("LOCATION", 0);
    double latitude = Double.parseDouble(mPreferences.getString(History.KEY_LAT, "0.0"));
    double longitude = Double.parseDouble(mPreferences.getString(History.KEY_LON, "0.0"));

      LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
      marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
        // Showing the current location in Google Map
      map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        // Zoom in the Google Map
      map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
}
```

Remember to declare the Map and Marker variable as *static* globally. like

```
    static Marker marker;
    static GoogleMap map;
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of replacing the fragment every time you can create one instance of a Fragment that contains your Map and instead of replacing it every time just use the `hide` and `show` method of the `FragmentTransaction`. In the map fragment create a method that create a marker to the `GoogleMap` and call it when you are adding a marker to it.

**example:**

create a global instance of the Fragment

```
private Fragment frag;
```

**in displayView**

```
private void displayView(int position) {
  ChildrenLocationDetails collection = result.get(position);      
  if(frag == null)
  {
       Fragment frag = newInstance(collection.getLatitude(), collection.getLongitude());
       getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, frag).commit(); 
  }else
  {
       frag.createMarker(collection.getLatitude(), collection.getLongitude());
       getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().show(frag).commit();
  }

}
```

and if you want to hide the fragment

```
       getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(frag).commit();
```

in this way you dont need to keep reloading map all over again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Can you give a small example.